# gitlab cicd: child pipeline not trigger from parent pipeline(child and parent are in different repos)

Tags: gitlab, cicd

**Parent Pipeline**

```
stages: 
- build

build_project_A:
 stage: build
 when: manual
 trigger:
  project: /home/demo/demo-project
  branch: cicd-test
  startegy: depend
```

**Child Pipeline:**

```
stages:
 - build

build_demo_project:
 stage: build
 rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"
 script:
  - mvn clean install
```

Now i am trying to trigger child pipeline from parent pipeline(multi project pipeline), but not trigger child pipeline and getting error in parent pipeline itself.
**error: "down stream pipeline can't be created. Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. the rules configuration prevented anu jobs from being added to the pipeline".**
Please help me how to fix this.
***OR***
**how to trigger child pipeline manually on it's own and also child pipeline should trigger manually from other project pipeline.**

Answer (score 1):

Because you use multi-project pipelines (not parent-child pipelines), the correct rule will be:

```yaml
if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"
```

See more: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline#use-rules-to-control-downstream-pipeline-jobs

Comment: Thanks you @Muravyev Maxim. It's working now